# Modo Debug e Release no Visual Studio, para que serve?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, debug, release

No meu *Visual Studio* eu reparei que existe duas configurações que eu não consigo compreender para que elas servem, são elas **Debug** e **Release**, faz parte da opção *Solution Confugurations*. Alguém poderia me explicar para que serve essas duas opções?

Debug:

[image: SS]

Release:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

*PS: Atualmente estou usando o Visual Studio para desenvolver em C#.*

Comment: Para qual linguagem?

Comment: Vou editar aqui.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Basicamente é uma forma de escolher quais configurações serão usadas para criar o projeto. Estas são comuns e já vem com o Visual Studio mas é possível criar suas próprias configurações. Veja `Configuration Manager...` no menu.

Quando escolhe uma delas está escolhendo um arquivo que contém toda a mecânica que será usada para gerar o projeto. O modo *debug* prepara o ambiente para a verificação e não para execução em produção.

Em geral isto cria uma variável de compilação (`DEBUG`) que poderá ser usada internamente pelo compilador para decidir o que compilar baseado em diretivas do código (compilação condicional) e atributos usados. Além disto é gerado um arquivo (`.pdb`) com dados adicionais para ajudar na depuração do código. Obviamente o código é gerado para facilitar o teste e não para rodar rápido e com pouco consumo.

O [JITter](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/146250/101) e o GC se comportam diferentemente quando estão em modo *debug*.

O modo *release*, claro, gera um projeto limpo, otimizado e pronto para uso em produção. Algumas tarefas pós-compilação costumam ser usadas neste modo.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Mais uma vez obrigado pela resposta bigown. Vou utilizar o modo release quando for gerar os arquivos do projeto.