# O que é um JITter?

Tags: terminologia, compilação, compiladores, runtime

No contexto do desenvolvimento de software o que é um JITter?

Cada vez se fala mais nisso e várias linguagens estão usando a tão falada compilação JIT.

No que ele difere de um compilador?

Comment: (parcialmente) relacionada: [Como funciona a execução de uma aplicação .Net?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/118694/18246)

Comment: @jbueno Eu fiz o parzinho justamente porque cito JITTer em muitos lugares e não tem uma boa referência para quem quer saber mais. Vou editar essas respostas e ver se preciso complementar algo aqui para dar um contexto que atenda todos casos.

Comment: É JITer ou JITTer? Ou seja, é com 1 ou com 2 t's?

Comment: @VictorStafusa a Wikipedia tá do jeito que eu fiz, sei lá se ela tá correta: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jitter_(disambiguation)

Comment: @bigown Achei que isso fosse JIT, e que Jitter fosse uma medida de comunicação em rede.

Comment: @MurilloGoulart JIT é a ação, JITter é o executor da ação.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

JITter é abreviação de Just-In-Time Compiler ou compilador sob demanda. Podemos considerá-lo como um compilador dinâmico já que roda em tempo de execução e pode ir adaptando o código conforme necessidade.

Ao contrário do compilador tradicional, geralmente chamado de AOT (Ahead Of Time), ele só funciona durante a execução da aplicação. É comum ser necessário quando a aplicação foi gerada em alguma forma intermediária e roda em alguma máquina virtual que gerará um [código binário a ser executado pelo processador](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/142289/101). É como se ele criasse o código efetivamente executável em memória quando precisa. Mas também pode fazer diretamente em código fonte de uma linguagem.

É um mecanismo bem antigo, existente desde que temos linguagens de mais alto nível. Só mais recentemente se popularizou.

Ele também difere de um interpretador porque ele gera um código binário executável e o interpretador usa alguma forma de seleção do que executar. Não dá para comparar a eficiência, tamanha a diferença. Também é comum que o interpretador tenha que interpretar novamente em cada ciclo de execução enquanto que o JITTer pode rodar apenas uma vez naquele código não importando quantas vezes rodará.

O principal objetivo deste tipo de compilador é dar melhor performance, comparando com a interpretação. Em ambientes onde a compilação JIT é feita em cima do código fonte o ganho é óbvio.

Em caso onde já há uma compilação prévia também pode haver um ganho por poder dar melhor adaptação ao ambiente real de execução e poder fazer otimizações globais mesmo em código que são *linkados* dinamicamente. Mas na verdade o objetivo nesses casos é facilitar o uso em diversas plataformas diferentes com a mesma distribuição.

## Funcionamento

Existem algumas estratégias de funcionamento. Alguns rodam logo no início na carga da aplicação, outros vão compilando conforme as funções vão sendo chamadas, outros tentam equilibrar essas duas formas. Alguns vão recompilando com melhores otimizações conforme a aplicação vai executando e vai coletando estatísticas de uso (chamado de *hotspot*). É possível até mesmo partir de um código nativo gerado previamente e o JITter ir regerando novo código binário para substituir partes onde ele descobriu na execução que pode ser mais eficiente.

É raro eles serem tão inteligentes e ideais assim. Dizem que um JITter pode, em teoria, produzir códigos melhores que os produzidos por compiladores tradicionais AOT, mas na prática não vemos isso ocorrendo.

Em alguns casos pode haver um pré-JIT que antecipa a compilação sob demanda e guarda o executável binário antes da execução. Ainda pode ser considerado um JITter porque é executado no local que haverá a execução da aplicação. Isso pode ajudar a carga da aplicação ser mais rápida já que o JITter costuma atrasar seu início até ter algo pronto para a execução.

É muito comum que um JITter não faça muitas otimizações já que isso toma muito tempo. Ele tem que responder rápido, ter baixa latência. Os mais inteligentes podem melhorar as otimizações conforme percebe que o ganho supera o custo de melhor análise. Ele pode se beneficiar de informações só obtidas em tempo de execução para tomar a melhor decisão, mas o AOT já conta com técnicas que permite otimização por estatística. Alguns possuem camadas e quanto mais ele percebe que algo é usado com frequência mais o JITter faz otimizações.

A presença de um pré-compilador reduz o custo da compilação JIT já que ele pode cuidar de vários aspectos onde é melhor definir antecipadamente. Normalmente [esse pré-compilador funciona como um *frontend*, enquanto que o JITter funciona como um *backend*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/104814/101). Ele pode ser um compilador completo e manter as duas partes, caso típico dos JITters que rodam com base um código fonte.

Há casos onde o código alvo não é um binário.

[Exemplo de como fazer um JITter simples](http://nullprogram.com/blog/2015/03/19/).

## Uso

Muitas linguagens dinâmicas possuem implementações que fazem isso. É o caso da maioria da máquinas virtuais quem rodam JavaScript. [Lua tem um JITTer lendário](http://luajit.org/). PHP deve ter em breve.

SQL costuma rodar desta forma nos principais banco de dados. Todos eles geram o código nativo ou intermediário a partir do código fonte.

As linguagens estáticas mais famosas que usam compilação JIT são C# e Java que geram o código nativo a partir de um código intermediário gerado por um pré-compilador chamado *bytecode*. Teoricamente qualquer linguagem pode ter um JITter.

Os JITters tem conseguido dar performances muito boas porque fazem a compilação em tempo de execução. Se falava que um JITter suficientemente bom poderia fazer os códigos serem mais otimizados que um gerado de forma AOT, e de fato hoje acontece em alguns pontos. Ainda tem o que melhorar, mas já é uma realidade parcial.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Então o C# também utiliza o pré compilador bytecode é isso mesmo ? Eu entendo que o C# tem duas compilações, que a primeira é para o MSIL e depois é gerado o código de máquina que no caso é o JIT que gera, é isso mesmo ? ou estou confundindo as coisas ?

Comment: O *bytecode* é o CIL ou MSIL como você chamou. Tecnicamente o CIL é a versão textual do código intermediário e o *bytecode* é a versão binária. Como eles têm relação um pra um, é quase a mesma coisa. Quando alguém fala que o CIL se transforma em código nativo, na verdade ela está falando do *bytecode*. Não está errado, só não é preciso.

Comment: Acabei pegando uma carona nesse post e ficou mais claro agora. https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/118694/como-funciona-a-execu%C3%A7%C3%A3o-de-uma-aplica%C3%A7%C3%A3o-net

Answer (score 0):

Apenas esclarecendo:

JIT ou JITer (com um "T") se refere a esta compilação Just In Time. (PROGRAMAÇÃO)

Já o Jitter (com 2 "T"s) é a medida de variação do atraso entre os pacotes sucessivos de dados ou variação no tempo de chegada dos pacotes, causada por congestionamento na rede. Representa a variação na latência. (REDES)

Comment: Ambos são com dois T's. "Sanduíche de vogal" em inglês provoca a duplicação da última consoante.