# Há diferença entre informar o tamanho na condição do laço ou fora dele?

Tags: java, desempenho, loop

Se eu tenho um array ou uma coleção em um `Arraylist` e preciso percorrer seus elementos, ocasionalmente preciso fazer uso de laço de repetição.

Ex.:

```
for(int i = 0; i < arrayList.size(); i++){
  //iteração...
}
```

ou no caso de um array simples:

```
for(int i = 0; i < vetor.length; i++){
  //iteração...
}
```

Porém, já vi em alguns fóruns<sup>1</sup> dizerem que informar o tamanho fora da condição do laço é melhor, pois à cada iteração o laço não precisa ficar verificando o tamanho da lista e consequentemente tornando rápido. Algo como:

```
int tamanho = arrayList.size();

for(int i = 0; i < tamanho; i++){
  //iteração...
}

//no caso do array

int tamanho = vetor.length;

for(int i = 0; i < tamanho; i++){
  //iteração...
}
```

Existe mesmo essa diferença de performance entre se informar o tamanho da lista fora ou na própria condição do laço?

<sub>*1 - não encontrei os links no momento.*</sub>.

Comment: No caso de um array não, pois `length` é uma propriedade, não é um método, [aqui](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17989270/for-loop-performance-storing-array-length-in-a-variable#comment-39830661) tem mais detalhes

Comment: +1, já li sobre em um livro de performance que falava sobre.

Comment: Uma simples mas boa pergunta. Nunca tinha pensado nisso. Começo agora a abrir mais minha mente para esses detalhes.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

De uma maneira geral o ganho será mínimo no caso do `ArrayList` que chama um método e tem algum custo.

Já [fizeram um teste no SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2383872/221800). O ganho realmente é muito baixo e só compensa se preocupar com isso se o corpo do laço é muito rápido, aí a chamada do método várias vezes pode pesar.

No caso do *array*  haverá um ganho menor ainda. Ambos acessam uma variável de forma direta, a única diferença é que o acesso à propriedade exigirá um acesso indireto (através de um ponteiro) ao objeto e o acesso à variável local será feita logo ali diretamente.

Acho que não em Java, mas em C# mesmo uma propriedade seria feito *inline* tendo o mesmo ganho do *array*.

## Otimização

Também não digo que tenha algum mal em sempre preferir fazer o cache do valor antes. A não ser que o compilador ou [JITter](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/146250/101) faça alguma otimização por ter o tamanho verificado dentro do laço e quando o tamanho é verificado fora a otimização não ocorra. Normalmente há grande ganho em retirar a verificação de estouro de faixa de acesso dentro do laço se o compilador/JITter consegue identificar que nunca sairá do limite. Uma das formas de garantir isso é usar um `for each`. Outra é o compilador ser inteligente e verificar que a condição mais o uso sempre produz índices dentro da faixa. A verificação é feita dentro do laço. O que está fora do laço não é uma informação confiável, pode até dar erro como demonstro abaixo.

## Semântica

Mas note que além da performance pode ter um motivo melhor para fazer o cache do tamanho. A semântica é diferente nos dois casos.

Você não deveria fazer isso, mas se mudar o tamanho da coleção de dados dentro do laço e o tamanho foi cacheado fora dele, pode não ter o resultado esperado. O dado que indica o fim do laço não bate mais com a realidade do objeto.

Fiz um exemplo mostrando a diferença:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;

class Main {
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception {
        ArrayList<Integer> x = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        x.add(1); x.add(2); x.add(3); x.add(4); x.add(5);
        for (int i = 0; i < x.size(); i++) {
            if (i % 2 == 0) { //retira os elementos pares
                x.remove(i);
            }
            System.out.println("Tamanho atual = " + x.size() + ", i = " + i); //só para ajudar visualizar
        }
        System.out.println("---");
        for (int i = 0; i < x.size(); i++) System.out.println(x.get(i));
        System.out.println("---------------------");
        x = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        x.add(1); x.add(2); x.add(3); x.add(4); x.add(5);
        int tamanho = x.size();
        for (int i = 0; i < tamanho; i++) {
            if (i % 2 == 0) x.remove(i);
            System.out.println("Tamanho atual = " + x.size() + ", i = " + i); //só para ajudar visualizar
        }
        System.out.println("---");
        for (int i = 0; i < x.size(); i++) System.out.println(x.get(i));
    }
}
```

Veja [como fica no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/oDCusV). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/yavhtauh-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Algorithm/SizeInLoop.java). Dá erro estourando a faixa existente, porque o laço está com uma informação defasada.

Existe outro problema de semântica diferente que não é o caso da pergunta, mas vale a informação. Pode ser que use um método para pegar um valor e decidir se deve encerrar o laço. Esse método pode ter um efeito colateral. É desejável que esse efeito ocorra em cada iteração ou só deve ocorrer uma vez? Isso é importante.

Comment: E como eu posso testar isso? Tem algum jeito ou o resultado é tão ínfimo que não da pra reproduzir e calcular a diferença facilmente?

Comment: Testar o que? a diferença entre eles? Viu o *link* que eu coloquei?

Comment: Ah sim, desatenção minha, ainda não tinha acessado e visto o teste de lá.

Comment: @bigown, gostaria de fazer um adendo. Considerando a melhor forma de varrer um objeto List é usar as interfaces Collection e os seus respectivos métodos iterator() que por sua vez podemos usar o iterator.hasNext() para iterar com os elementos de um Array ou ArrayList.

Answer (score 18):

Sim, mesmo podendo ser ínfima a diferença.

A logica é simples, comparar um valor será mais rápido que ter de executar um método para obter o valor.

No caso de ser uma propriedade como [comentado pelo @Marco](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/152521/h%C3%A1-diferen%C3%A7a-entre-informar-o-tamanho-na-condi%C3%A7%C3%A3o-do-la%C3%A7o-ou-fora-dele#comment314812_152521), só muda a posição na memoria então não tem diferença.

### Exemplos

- Digamos que você tenha um método `len()` que retorna o numero de caracteres de uma string e ela demore (hipoteticamente) 1.5ms para ser executada.
- Digamos que a comparação demore 0.5ms para ser executada.

#### 1

```
var str = 'name';
for(var i = 0; i < len(str); i++){ 
    // AQUI VOCÊ TERA UM TOTAL DE 8ms DE EXECUÇÃO.
    // 6ms = 4x1.5 das 4 chamadas de len().
    // 2ms = 4x0.5 das 4 comparações. 
}
```

#### 2

```
var str = 'name';
var len = len(str);
for(var i = 0; i < len; i++){ 
    // AQUI VOCÊ TERA UM TOTAL DE 3.5ms DE EXECUÇÃO
    // 1.5ms = 1x1.5 da 1 chamadas de len().
    // 2ms = 4x0.5 das 4 comparações. 
}
```

### Adendo

Deve se ter cuidado com a utilização de chamadas direto no laço. Pois pode se alterado a cada iteração.

#### Exemplo

```js
var mask = '###########';
function countChar(str, char){
 return str.split(char).length-1;
}
for(var i = 0; i < countChar(mask, '#'); i++){ // AQUI A COMPARAÇÃO VAI DIMINUINDO A CADA LAÇO POIS SEMPRE É CHAMADO O MÉTODO.
 var split = mask.split('');
    split[i] = 1;
    mask = split.join('');
}
console.log(mask);
```

Comment: Acessar uma propriedade e uma variável local tem diferença.

Comment: A diferença seria em nível de acesso, de 1 loop direto, 2 loops "struct->propriedade" ? seria praticamente 0, mas compreendo sua critica.

Comment: a diferença seria um acesso ou dois acesso, não tem anda de *loop*. Praticamente zero não é zero. Não sei se você notou que a pergunta é sobre Java e não JavaScript. Em JS pode ser que exista situações diferentes, inclusive dependendo do *engine* usado.

Answer (score 4):

Considerando a imagem a seguir:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

---

```
public class DemostrateFor {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        int ctr = 12;
        for( int j=10, k=14;
              j <= k;
              ++j, k=k-1, ctr++ )
        {
            System.out.println(j+":"+k+":"+ctr);
        }
    }
}
```

---

E considerando também o próprio recurso da linguagem: `O loop for melhorado`.

```
for (String val : myList)
     System.out.println(val);
```

---

Então, sim: existe diferença entre informar o tamanho na **condição de terminação** do `loop for`. A performance do *loop* é diretamente afetada no caso de informarmos a **condição de terminação** erradamente, isso é, chamando um método a cada iteração, sendo que o java resolve isso internamente usando `O loop for melhorado`. Desta forma liberando o programador para se preocupar com a recursividade ou melhoria na lógica a ser usada nas iterações.

---

Acredito que seja isso. Obrigado pela pergunta e por isso, pela oportunidade em aprender.

#### Referência:

[MALA GUPTA, 2013], **OCA Java SE 7 Programmer I

 Certification Guide**: PREPARE FOR THE 1Z0-803 EXAM