# Desempenho de variável temporária dentro de loop

Tags: java, variáveis, desempenho, for

Durante a faculdade um professor comentou comigo que declarar uma variável antes de um `loop` e reutilizá-la era uma forma econômica e mais interessante de se fazer. Por Exemplo (em Java):

```
 String str;
 for(Pessoa p : pessoas){
    str = p.getNome();

    //faz algumas operações com str
 }
```

Trabalhando em uma empresa de programação vejo meus colegas de trabalho experientes declararem dentro do *loop* e afirmam que não tem diferença alguma.

```
 for(Pessoa p : pessoas){
    String str = p.getNome();

    //faz algumas operações com str
 }
```

Deixo aqui minha dúvida, existe mesmo alguma diferença de performance ou desempenho entre essas duas formas de declaração de variáveis temporárias?

Comment: Relacionada: [Boas práticas em declaração de variáveis em um for](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/170393/91) tem uma outra pergunta (que não achei) sobre o custo de alguns estilos for(s) interessante também.

Comment: Depende do compilador, não tenho certeza mas creio que todos os compiladores modernos gerarão o mesmo código para uma ou outra versão. Experimente "descompilar" esses dois exemplos usando `javap` e veja o que acontece. Para mais detalhes, ver a pergunta sugerida pelo @rray.

Comment: Relacionada/achada :P [Há diferença entre informar o tamanho na condição do laço ou fora dele?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/152521/91)

Comment: @rray mas essa ñ tem tanto a ver assim, tem semântica diferente sempre que o valor a ser comparado puder ser modificado em cada passo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Primeiro, tem certeza que a comparação é essa mesmo? Claro que atribuir um valor fora do laço é para ser mais rápido. Já declarar deveria ser igual. Mas não necessariamente.

Tem que medir. E precisa medir em várias situações diferentes. Mesmo que dê diferença, eu acho que será pequena.

Note que pode ser que exista até semântica diferente em declarar fora ou dentro do laço. Não sei como está em Java. Posso pesquisar. Mas concordo com o comentário do mgibsonbr, não deve ter diferença na maioria das situações.

O primeiro cria uma variável fora e depois vai atribuindo novos valores em cada passo. No segundo a variável é criada novamente e o valor é atribuído.

Alguns pessoas vão pensar que criar a variável novamente terá um custo de memória ou de processamento, mas não precisa acontecer. Em geral será alocado no meu local da *stack* e nenhum processamento será necessário. Então é para ser igual. Mas não garanto que não tenha exceções em circunstâncias específicas. Teria que ler a especificação para ver se não tem alguma pegadinha.

Eu optaria pelo que é o mais correto semanticamente para o caso, ou se não fizer diferença eu acho que seria declarar dentro do laço, a não ser que eu precise de performance e uma análise minuciosa demonstre que declarar fora é melhor.

Uma dica que não está relacionada com o caso exposto: experiência quantitativa é diferente de qualitativa. Conheço programadores com 30 anos de experiência que fazem tudo errado e não fazem questão de melhorar. Tem professores que são ciosos do que estão ensinando e outros não. Muitas vezes o professor fala uma coisa e o aluno entende outra :)