# É possível um programa modificar o seu próprio código?

Tags: c#, .net

Eu estava desenvolvendo um programa de inteligencia artificial com redes neurais, mas o que sempre me deixava encabulado é que toda vez que eu abrir o programa, ele vai ter que repetir todo o percurso de aprendizado para chegar ao mesmo resultado de antes.

Minha dúvida então é, é possível o programa modificar o seu próprio código fonte e modificar os valores das variáveis? Se sim, como?

#### Exemplo:

Meu programa termina sua execução com a variável `count = 3`, então da próxima vez que ele for aberto, será atribuído o valor `3` para `count` novamente.

---

#### Por que não guardar esses valores em um arquivo `txt` ou `xml`?

Porque eu gostaria que, qualquer pessoa sem arquivos externos, poderia usar meu programa, de onde parou.

Comment: Um programa compilado modificar seu proprio codigo fonte? Se isso existir, eu quero aprender como usar :p

Comment: Se não quer arquivos externos, pode usar webservice, nuvem, alguma coisa online. Agora se não pode ser online, ai complica.

Comment: Sim, não gostaria de usar nada online, até porque, o ambiente em que eu vou usar este código, nem tem acesso a internet.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Primeiro, não é necessário alterar o código para evitar repetir o aprendizado. Não tenho conhecimento profundo sobre IA, até porque é bem mais complicado do que as pessoas acham que é, mas sei que o aprendizado não é sobre gerar novos códigos por conta própria.

Se fosse e não pudesse alterar o próprio código então seria impossível fazer isto.

Então claro que pode alterar o próprio código. Os [JITters](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/146250/101) fazem isso o tempo todo.

Mesmo que isso esteja disponível não seria muito difícil fazer um mecanismo que altere os fontes e gere um novo executável.

Se quiser só mudar no executável dá também, precisa saber onde colocar nele. Me parece muita gambiarra.

> Minha dúvida então é, é possível o programa modificar o seu próprio código fonte e modificar os valores das variáveis? Se sim, como?

Valores das variáveis são mudadas o tempo todo, por isso eles levam este nome.

> Meu programa termina sua execução com a variável count = 3, então da próxima vez que ele for aberto, será atribuído o valor 3 para count novamente.

Basta persistir o valor em algum lugar, não é necessário mudar o código. Quer persistir no executável? Pode, não acho recomendável.

> Porque eu gostaria que, qualquer pessoa sem arquivos externos, poderia usar meu programa, de onde parou.

Isso não é exatamente alterar o próprio código, é no máximo persistir dentro do executável.

Inclusive é possível usar [*resources*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_(Windows)) para armazenar esses valores já que o desejo é apenas não ter um arquivo externo, o que eu acho uma vantagem pouco necessária.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Conceptual.md).

Comment: O Hotswapping tem alguma coisa a ver com isso tambem?

Comment: Se for o que eu estou pensando, não.

Comment: Nunca ouvi falar de um programa Windows ser capaz de modificar os recursos embutidos nele; a API de recursos me parece completamente _read-only_. Será alguma alteração a partir do Vista?

Comment: @Wtrmute Não disse que tem API para isto, tem como modificar. É força bruta. Falo até que é gambiarra.