# Relação entre HotSpot e JVM, JDK/OpenJDK?

Tags: java, jvm, jdk, máquina-virtual

O que é Java HotSpot e qual sua relação com JVM e JDK/OpenJDK?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ele é uma das implementações da JVM, dentre as [muitas existentes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Java_virtual_machines). Ela não é a implementação original da JVM, mas logo se tornou a oficial. Criada pela Sun hoje pertencente à Oracle, mas baseada em algo já existente para outra linguagem em outra empresa comprada pela Sun. A grande inovação dela foi a inclusão de um [JITter](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/146250/101) adaptativo procurando o melhor código nativo de acordo com a necessidade do código que está rodando. Este é um dos pontos fortes de Java permitindo que a performance muitas vezes compense alguma deficiências da infraestrutura que dá a flexibilidade e segurança padrão da máquina virtual.

Conheça a [GraalVM](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/325531/101).