# O que significa "Rodar na JVM"?

Tags: terminologia, característica-linguagem, jvm

Linguagens como Scala, Kotlin, Clojure dentre outras "rodam na JVM".

- O que isso significa?
- O que a JVM fornece para elas?
- Até que ponto são "dependentes" da JVM?
- Elas só rodam na JVM?
- Essas linguagens geram um `.class` igual ao Java para rodarem na JVM?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> O que isso significa?

Significa que essas linguagens geram um "binário" compatível com a JVM, que ela é capaz de entender, que segue todos os protocolos especificados por essa plataforma. É como dizer que uma aplicação é capaz de rodar no Windows, ou mesmo no ARM.

> O que a JVM fornece para elas?

Um ambiente de execução que "interpreta" o *bytecode*, gera códigos nativos para a plataforma em nível mais abaixo ([JITter](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/146250/101)), gerenciamento de memória (GC) e segurança, toda infraestrutura para interoperar com outras aplicações e componentes externos à JVM, e também uma ampla biblioteca, embora tecnicamente não faça parte da JVM, mas de algo que sempre está junto dela, formando o JRE (Java Runtime Enviroment). Enfim, ela é uma máquina virtual simulando um processador e um sistema operacional dentro de um padrão específico onde as aplicações podem se focar, deixando para esta máquina entender-se com as plataformas reais onde vão executar.

> Até que ponto são "dependentes" da JVM?

A linguagem em si não deveria ser, mas é comum que mesmo a linguagem precise de recursos específicos da plataforma que roda. Na verdade não é bem a JVM que é o problema, é a biblioteca disponível para a plataforma que normalmente é adotada pela linguagem que praticamente torna a linguagem dependente daquela plataforma. Não que não tenha solução, mas se torna complicado compatibilizar em outra plataforma.

> Elas só rodam na JVM?

Nada impede que rodem onde elas quiserem a não ser que tenha especificação em contrário ou que tenha algo que só a JVM possa fornecer, o que costuma ser improvável. Veja [Relação entre HotSpot e JVM, JDK/OpenJDK?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/227073/101).

> Essas linguagens geram um `.class` igual ao Java para rodarem na JVM?

Geralmente sim, mas é possível que alguma linguagem crie uma infraestrutura que torne o acesso de forma diferente.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Legal! Muito obrigado pela resposta! Eu recebi um -1.. Você sabe o pq? Fiz algo de errado?

Comment: Que eu saiba não, tem gente que negativa porque é possível obter a resposta em outro local, mas não tem aqui.

Comment: Clojure é um exemplo de linguagem que pode rodar na JVM e no browser (javascript). É como se uma linguagem fosse hospedada em outra. A linguagem hospedada permite chamar métodos, criar classes e instanciar objetos da linguagem "hospedeira".

Comment: A vantagem é que geralmente as linguagens que rodam na JVM têm uma sintaxe mais simples e menos burocrática que o Java.