# O que é a GraalVM?

Tags: java, jvm, máquina-virtual

No que ela é diferente da JVM? E por que criaram ela? Qual vantagem de usar ela?

Pode usar em mobile?

É oficial da Oracle? Está pronta para uso? Tem alguma restrição?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Não tome minha resposta como definitiva porque não a conheço e também porque foi escrita em momento inicial da tecnologia, mas ela é uma nova infraestrutura de máquina virtual criada pela Oracle com algumas vantagens em relação à JVM "oficial". Na verdade, ela ainda depende da JVM para funcionar, mas não sei se no futuro é pra ser 100% independente (parece que acabou tendo isso). É tudo escrito em Java mesmo, e isto já é um diferencial.

Eu acho que a GraalVM foi uma resposta ao [.NET Core](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/40671/101) ([Por que o .NET Core foi criado?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/225927/101)). Ela é uma forma de diminuir a burocracia e os problemas da JVM, e ser mais adequado ao uso em cenários onde a JVM é muito pesada e pouco modular, principalmente em nuvem, em imagens "containerizadas".

Ela foi criada pensando melhor em uso de várias linguagens. A JVM podia fazer isto, mas não foi pensada inicialmente para isto. Há ganhos de performance porque se torna natural.

Ela não é só uma VM. Tem outras partes como um novo compilador e um JITter que pode ser usado antecipadamente gerando o código nativo antes de executar, então funciona mais como um AOT compiler, o que dá mais performance (na maioria das vezes).

Ela tem duas partes: [Native Image](https://www.graalvm.org/latest/reference-manual/native-image/) e [Truffle](https://www.graalvm.org/latest/reference-manual/java-on-truffle/).

Tudo isto tem o intuito de melhorar a performance, diminuir a dependência do C++ que é problemático para dar manutenção. Isto permite o uso dentro de aplicações nativas como uma espécie de *script*.

Enfim, procura mecanismos para atender as novas demandas que a indústria começou exigir.

## Mobile

Até onde eu sei pode usar normalmente em qualquer situação onde a JVM podia ser usada antes, desde que possa instalá-la. Não é o caso normal do Android que tem sua VM própria do Java. Não digo que será impossível usá-la junto, mas não acontece em primeiro momento. Ainda não sei se ela só pode estender a JVM ou é compatível com outras VMs. No iOS você tem que implantar a VM junto com a aplicação então ela parece bem adequada e se bobear foi um dos motivos para criarem a GraalVM, mas parece que não foi usada assim, o que me deixa confuso.

## Conclusão

É possível testá-la desde o JDK 9 e melhorado no JDK 10 em diante. E até onde sei pode usar em produção sim.

Só o tempo dirá se terá sucesso.

[Site oficial](https://www.graalvm.org/).

Eu respondi mais com base no que entendo do .NET Core do que a GraalVM.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Conceptual.md).