# Layout programaticamente ou no XML

Tags: android, xml, ui

Fiz um *layout* em XML, com o tempo comecei a perceber que o layout programaticamente tem mais facilidade de modelar a tela conforme a interação do usuário. Programaticamente é melhor que em XML? E se for, existe algum "tutorial" de criação?

Comment: Antes de qualquer coisa, comece fazendo o [tour](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender como a comunidade funciona; depois leia o guia de [Como perguntar](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) para verificar como pode melhorar sua pergunta e, por fim, acesse a [central de ajuda](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help) para verificar vários artigos que te lhe ajudarão a entender melhor o site.

Comment: Desculpe, foi a pressa e frustação em enviar a pergunta. Vou ter mais cuidado nas futuras dúvidas....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

De forma geral é gosto, mas dá para afirmar que o código imperativo (o que está chamando de programaticamente) sempre será mais flexível ou poderoso, a não ser que a tecnologia tenha muita "mágica", e mesmo assim só será melhor em alguns pontos específicos onde a mágica foi criada. A forma declarativa (que o AP chama de XML) pode ser mais prática em certos pontos porque elimina certo *boilerplate* e adiciona alguns, e permite uma forma que *designers* estão mais acostumados, principalmente se já usou HTML. A forma declarativa, apesar de ser usada para dar informações para a aplicação programar o dispositivo computacional, não é exatamente programação. Uma forma declarativa nunca consegue ter o poder da programação.

Se quer fazer *layouts* dinâmicos então a solução quase sempre é fazer programaticamente. Tem algumas formas para dar certo dinamismo de forma declarativa, mas é bem limitado.

Não conheço o *stack* de tecnologia do Android em profundidade, mas a forma declarativa tende a ser mais lenta, principalmente se isto é interpretado em tempo de execução. Mesmo que um código seja gerado em tempo de compilação partindo da declaração feita no XML, ainda deve ficar mais lento. É como comparar uma linguagem de alto nível com Assembly (bem feito), é muito difícil a linguagem de alto nível produzir um Assembly tão otimizado quanto dá para fazer na mão. A questão é fazer bem feito, fazer o código na mão pode até ser pior se for mal feito, mas é mais raro acontecer este tipo de erro, a pessoa tem que ser muito sem noção, ao contrário do que acontece com Assembly que tem outro nível de abstração.

Esse custo de performance pode até ser intermediário, ou seja, gerar um código da linguagem de programação no processo de [JITting](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/146250/101).

Também não sei se tem alguma desvantagem fazer em código, tem tecnologia que usa uma forma de XML que tem um código para distribuir muito menor.

De forma geral as pessoas usam a forma declarativa também porque tem mais documentação e mais suporte da comunidade, afinal se todo mundo faz assim pode obter mais ajuda.

Eu gosto mais de fazer com código, mas não descarto fazer algo declarativo se me mostrar vantagens ou for necessário por algum motivo que foge do meu controle. Não tem melhor, tem gosto e necessidade. Se a pessoa não souber programar com código imperativo pode ser pior. Então se está com alguma dificuldade precisa saná-las, não existe forma automática de resolver isso. Desenvolver software é difícil e precisa dominar tudo para alcançar bons resultados.

Comment: Entendi, muito obrigado, no que estou fazendo, mesmo não entendendo direto, o código imperativo fica mais interessante. Vou estudar mais sobre, me ajudou muito sua informação... Obrigado

Answer (score 2):

O que é melhor em programação depende do contexto. A mesma abordagem pode ser melhor numa situação e não o ser noutra.

A utilização do xml é na maioria das situações, por ser declarativa, mais eficiente na perspectiva do programador. Você diz o que quer e o Android fica encarregue do "como o fazer".

No Java é possível fazer tudo o que é feito por xml mas é mais "trabalhoso" e necessita de um bom [conhecimento de como as "coisas" funcionam](https://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Creating_an_Android_User_Interface_in_Java_Code), já que tem de ser você a dizer como se faz. No entanto, é mais versátil.
Uma das razões para utilizá-lo será aquela que refere: layouts dinâmicos, em função de inputs do utilizador.

Neste momento está em desenvolvimento uma api([Jetpack Compose](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose)) que permite construir de forma declarativa layouts directamente no código, no caso usando Kotlin.

Comment: Obrigado, quero fazer muitas interações dinâmicas, e achei de fato mais interessante em código imperativo. Vou estudar mais sobre...