# Por que certas linguagens são mais rápidas que outras?

Tags: desempenho, característica-linguagem, independente-de-linguagem

Já ouvi falar muito sobre como C é mais rápido que C++ e Java, Lua é a linguagem de *script* mais rápida, entre outros exemplos.

O que faz com que certas linguagens sejam mais rápidas que outras? O que define uma linguagem como "rápida"? Por exemplo, velocidade de execução de uma instrução, a velocidade em que o programa roda, entre outros.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> Já ouvi falar muito sobre como C é mais rápido que C++ e Java, Lua é a linguagem de script mais rápida, entre outros exemplos.

## Linguagens não são mais rápidas

Não é bem assim, linguagens não são rápidas ou lentas, elas podem ter mais capacidade para facilitar algumas coisas serem executadas mais rapidamente ou não. Inclusive em algumas operações uma linguagem pode se sair melhor e em outras ir pior quando compara com outra linguagem.

Existem implementações de linguagens que podem ser mais rápidas ou mais lentas.

Muitas vezes a diferença está até na biblioteca usada pela linguagem e não ela em si.

## Comparações

Não é para C ser mais rápida que C++, de forma geral. Quem fala isto é que deve explicar porque isso aconteceria. Há vários casos em que C++ consegue ser mais rápido dentro do padrão.

Boa parte do fato que os compiladores dessas linguagens geram código melhor é a cultura em fazer isto.

Há casos que depende de como você vai fazer, pode até conseguir fazer mais rápido mas o preço que paga por isso é alto demais também. Não é difícil ver alguns [códigos em C# rodarem mais rápido que C++](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ricom/2005/05/10/performance-quiz-6-chineseenglish-dictionary-reader/) (hoje mais fácil ainda), mas se houver um esforço bom para melhorar o código C++ ele conseguir bater o C#. Não é a C++ que é mais rápido, é a cultura em torno dela que costuma produzir códigos rápidos.

Tem certos padrões de uso de memória (muito comum) que faz o *tracing* GC ser mais rápido que o GC simples ou gerenciamento manual comum e apenas o gerenciamento muito cuidadoso e trabalhoso consegue bater o que o .NET ou JVM conseguem.

Sem falar que existem implementações muito diferentes do que as pessoas estão acostumadas, por exemplo tem C interpretada que é bem lenta.

## *Script*

Claro que linguagens cuja implementação dependem de interpretação ou uma máquina virtual para rodar serão mais lentas, pelo menos em certa medida, existe um processo extra a ser realizado na execução. Mas ainda é uma questão de implementação, porque toda linguagem poderia ser implementada de um jeito ou outro, a não ser que a especificação determine ou proíba alguma forma.

Lua é rápida porque tem uma máquina virtual muito eficiente e simples (simplicidade é o segredo, por isso a indústria do software tem ido para um caminho ruim). Claro que a linguagem foi pensada para não exigir uma VM muito complexa.

## *JITter*

Em alguns casos ter alguém interessado em fazer algo bom ajuda, Lua é rápida no padrão, mas é mais ainda com LuaJIT porque teve um cara muito bom nisso interessando em fazer um [JITter](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/146250/101). Como ele não está mais no projeto, não há evolução que poderia ter.

Hoje acho que é fácil dizer que JavaScript é a linguagem de *script* mais rápida depois que inicia (o JITter tem um custo um pouco alto), justamente porque existem grandes fornecedores interessados que ela execute muito rápido. Ela pode, ainda que difícil, executar alguns casos mais rápido que C por ter a chance de se adaptar durante a execução (não sei se alguém fez isto).

## Abstrações que ajudam ou atrapalham

É claro que algumas linguagens possuem construções que escondem custo de processamento, principalmente do programador ingênuo, então não é que ela é mais lenta, ela está te dando alguma facilidade que tem um custo, e em alguns casos você paga mesmo que não precise.

C++ é uma linguagem que tem essas abstrações sem custo algum ou se tiver só paga se você precisar. Então se precisar é para ter um custo igual ao C, ao melhor porque há casos que consegue expressar melhor a intenção dando mais oportunidade de otimização.

C tem um problema com a flexibilidade dela. Por deixar fazer muita coisa o compilador tem que ser mais cuidadoso na hora de otimizar.

> O que faz com que certas linguagens sejam mais rápidas que outras? O que define uma linguagem como "rápida"? (por exemplo, velocidade de execução de uma instrução, a velocidade em que o programa roda, entre outros)

Nada define uma linguagem como rápida, isto é um conceito errado. O máximo que dá para dizer que a linguagem, sua biblioteca, as implementações vigentes e a cultura dos usuários de determinada linguagem costumam produzir aplicações que são mais rápidas ou eficientes (que é melhor que ser rápida, porque ser rápido é algo quase ambíguo e ingênuo).

Velocidade de execução da instrução é determinada pelo processador e não pela linguagem.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Conceptual.md).